# Strange javascript object init?

Tags: javascript, variables, object, initialization

I recently came across this variable initialization in a WebGL tutorial:

```
var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 }, INTERSECTED;
```

I've never seen this format. I understand it's creating an object with an x and y property, but how is INTERSECTED related to the variable/object?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that `INTERSECTED` is just being initialized. like `var INTERSECTED;`

Comment: More info here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: @elclanrs: It's not actually the comma operator. It's just that the `var` statement uses the same character as a separator.

Comment: Exactly. That's what the wiki says, it provides the example of _separator_ as well as _operator_.

Comment: Thanks all! The answers always simpler than my brain wants to let it be.

Comment: I'm still somewhat new to StackOverflow- is it a good idea to retitle my question to something like "Multiple Variable Initialization of mixed types" to make it easier for others to find in the future?

Comment: Seems odd to give a link to a wikipedia article of what it's *not*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may get it wrong, but I think It is just like

```
var A=3,B;
```

Defines A with value 3 and B uninitialized.
INTERSECTED is just another var.

Answer (score 9):

The line is simply declaring two variables (`mouse` and `INTERSECTED`), and initializing `mouse` to `{ x: 0, y: 0}`.

`INTERSECTED` is not necessarily related to `mouse`, though clear code should only declare multiple variables together if they are highly related (even then, many prefer to declare every variable on a separate line).

Comment: They are highly related within the script, I think that is what threw me off. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

`INTERSECTED` isn't related to `mouse`.  It's just a one line way of initializing two variables.  I'm guessing that `INTERSECTED` is there so that it is treated as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my 2 cents: the usual convention is to write them on two separate lines and this certainly avoids any confusion:

```
var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 },
    INTERSECTED;
```

(also note that the convention is to have a four space indent which nicely aligns the variables)